# How can I upgrade parse-server to a new version?

Tags: mongodb, heroku, parse-server

I have a few apps (already working) running parse-server on Heroku and using mLab mongoDB.
I need to upgrade parse-server to a new version.

What is the simplest (an best) way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure compatibility by testing locally first, of course. To upgrade the version you change your project's package.json file.  There should be a dependency `"parse-server": "a.b.c"`

"a.b.c" will use an explicit version.
"~a.b.c" will use the latest version matching "a.b.*"
"^a.b.c" will use the latest version matching "a.*.*"

a is a major version, which is not always backwards compatible.
b is a minor version, which generally includes new features but should be backwards compatible, so ^ is **usually** safe to use.
c is a patch version, which is generally bug fixes and security updates, though I think parse-server has included minor feature updates here as well.

Comment: In my case the package.json file contains: "parse": "~1.8.0", and "parse-server": "*". What can I do? I suppose it should install the latest version. May be it did so when I ran "npm install parse-server". Would it be safe to rerun "npm install parse-server" now in order to upgrade?

Comment: Yeah it should be safe. I'm not sure how the Heroku configuration is set up, but that gets run every time we deploy an update to AWS so it's always on the latest we specify.

Comment: Hum? Looking at my mongoDB version, it does not seem it is using the last version of parse-server. But I may need to take a closer look.

Comment: MongoDB version? Mongo doesn't use parse-server, not sure what you mean.

Comment: No probably the opposite. I was told that I needed to upgrade my parse-server version in order get the right MongoDB version.

Comment: Ahh yeah original parse-server version is not tested against latest mongodb version.  It sounds like you're already using the later version of parse-server, though.